# Appending a list to a dictionary with keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to create a dictionary containing keys from an enumerated list that will assign the enumerated value as a key to the values of the list.

```
import string

dic = string.ascii_lowercase
s_dic = []
n_dic = {}    ## New Dictionary to contain numbers:letters

for i in dic:
    s_dic.append(i)  
for number, letter in enumerate(s_dic, start=1):
    print(number, '=', letter)
```

I have used `print` just to test the code worked. The output is as expected:

```
1 = a
2 = b
3 = c
4 = d
5 = e
6 = f
7 = g
8 = h
9 = i
10 = j
11 = k
12 = l
13 = m
14 = n
15 = o
16 = p
17 = q
18 = r
19 = s
20 = t
21 = u
22 = v
23 = w
24 = x
25 = y
26 = z
```

I want `n_dic` to contain `{1:a, 2:b etc}`

Comment: Can you be more clear about your input and expected output, and then the output you're getting now?

Comment: You don’t have any statements which insert anything into your dict. Have you come across this before?

Comment: I have edited the OP. I have not tried any methods to do this yet, here for some advice on it

Comment: See the answer from jaypeerachai, or better, the answer from SpgttCd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iiuc you can try

```
n_dic = {i: v for i, v in enumerate(s_dic, start=1)}
```

which is a standard way to initialize a dictionary and is called *dictionary comprehension*.

Comment: No, the initialization is done by a loop: _make something_ `for` _every single x_ `in` _some iterable X_. That's the way a loop works. So and now in Python you can use this _iterative structure_ to initialize data structures which contain more than one element, for example: a dictionary. As in a dictionary you have key-value-pairs connected by a colon, that's exactly what the _dictionary comprehension_ expects for each key value pair in the initialization loop, hence: `{key: value for key, value in zip(list1, list2)}`.

Comment: Note that this is analog to a _list comprehension_, which is there to create a list: `[element for element in iterable]`.

Comment: I see, so if I can for instance use `n_dic = {i*2: v for i, v in enumerate(s_dic, start=1)` and it will output `{2: 'a', 4: 'b'...}` but if i use `{i: v*2....}` it will output `{1: 'aa'}` so on and so forth? Im going to have a good read of the comprehension

Comment: Basically the brackets used show,  what kind of object is created here: `[]` for a list, `()` will produce a generator, `{}` a dictionary - but give attention: only with the aforementioned `key: value` syntax. With single objects, a comprehension with curly brackets will create a `set`...

Comment: Yes, you're beginning to get in touch with it. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can create dictionary right from enumerate

```
n_dic = dict(enumerate(s_dic, start=1))

>>> s_dic = list('abcdefg')
>>> dict(enumerate(s_dic, start=1))
{1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd', 5: 'e', 6: 'f', 7: 'g'}
```

Or even (thanks to @SayandipDutta)

```
dic = string.ascii_lowercase
dict(enumerate(dic, start=1))
```

Comment: This will directly work on OP's `dic` variable as well, which is a `string`.

Comment: @SayandipDutta Yes, i didn't think about